# Encryption with AES algorithm in Java

Tags: java, encryption, aes, packet

I made a packet p, with some integers and boolean values.  The packet is as follows:

```
TCPPacket p=new TCPPacket(481,516,23,42,true,false,false,false,false,false,false,false,10,10);
```

How can I encrypt the packet with AES, in Java?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read through the tutorial [Using AES with Java Technology](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/AES/AES_v1.html) from Oracle.

(First hit on Google btw.)

Comment: well the problem is that, with encryption i always change packet to string or maybe byte []... After encryption i cant reverse string (or byte []) to packet, in the form i create it... is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is some sample code that should get you started. It uses AES (128) to crypt and decrypt an object (using [SealedObject](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/site/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/crypto/SealedObject.html)).

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        TCPPacket packet = new TCPPacket(481, 516, 23, 42, true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, 10, 10);

        final char[] password = "secretpass".toCharArray();
        final byte[] salt = "a9v5n38s".getBytes();

        // Create key
        SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
        KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password, salt, 1024, 128);
        SecretKey tmp = factory.generateSecret(spec);
        SecretKey secret = new SecretKeySpec(tmp.getEncoded(), "AES");

        // Init ciphers
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        Cipher dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret);
        dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret);

        // Encrypt packet
        SealedObject so = new SealedObject(packet, cipher);

        // Decrypt packet
        TCPPacket decryptedPacket = (TCPPacket) so.getObject(dcipher);

        System.out.println(decryptedPacket.first);
    }

    private static class TCPPacket implements Serializable {
        private int first;
        public TCPPacket(final int _first, final int i1, final int i2, final int i3, final boolean b, final boolean b1,
                         final boolean b2, final boolean b3, final boolean b4, final boolean b5, final boolean b6,
                         final boolean b7, final int i4, final int i5) {

            first = _first;
        }
        public int getFirst() {
            return first;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much but can i ask something.? why you want to print decryptetPacket.first and not only decryptedPacket? With .first i just take 481 (the first integer in my packet. Without it is get sth like javaapplication7.Main$TCPPacket@228a02. So maybe i should do sth to get rid of javaapplication7.Main$TCPPacket@... or there is sth i dont get with your code?

Comment: It was just an example to show that the value inside the packet is actually decrypted ok.