# How to encrypt large amounts of data using asymmetric cryptography?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

In the client side of my application I want to encrypt text (that could be of any size) using a public key. After that I'll send this packet to a server. In the server side I want to decrypt this packet using my private key.

I can't use RSA, because the packet size could be of any size, even bigger then the key.
I can do that using OpenSSL, creating files and stuff with the results of Encrypt/Decrypt.

The question is: is there another way to programmatic do that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that OpenSSL breaks long texts into packets that it encodes separately.  Have you looked at it?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Security/Basicsymmetricencryptionexample.htm

Comment: Hi Mark. I can do that using OpenSSL, the problem is that the OpenSSL commands works creating files during the process. What I'm try to do now is to do the samething WITHOU creating those output files.

Comment: Does this provide any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262374/encryption-with-aes-algorithm-in-java ?

Comment: Hi SIMO, not it does not help. It uses a AES (Symmetric Key) to do the magic. What I am looking for is a way to use Assymmetric keys ( public and private) to encrypt/decrypt any size of packet :/

Comment: First, don't reinvent crypto; it's hard even for experts. Second, RSA has a hard limit of the key size in the payload it can encrypt, and operations with large keys are very expensive. That's why practical cryptosystems use symmetric encryption for the payload.

Comment: I don't understand. Why can't you simply write the java code to break the data up into appropriately sized blocks and then encrypt each block?

Comment: @GregS For one thing, an attacker could simply switch around all the blocks. You will have both a huge overhead with regards to CPU use as well as message size. Besides all that, it has been solved; use a hybrid encryption scheme. Why *wouldn't* you use hybrid crypto? *Important note*: you need to use authenticated encryption if you want to create a transport protocol. But in general, for transport, use TLS. For packet transport, use DTLS.

Comment: @owlstead: I was speaking not of the wisdom of his scheme but rather trying to zero in on what he is asking. It looks like he wants teh codez.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a [hybrid encryption scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). One example of such a scheme is OpenPGP.

In a hybrid encryption scheme, one generates a symmetric session key that is used just for one message. The symmetric key encrypts the payload, while the public key of the recipient(s) is used to encrypt the symmetric key. The payload is often signed by the private key of the sender. Finally, the whole lot is packaged together and sent out the door.

I would recommend you use something like [BouncyCastle](https://www.bouncycastle.org/java.html) to do OpenPGP encryption in Java. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

Use either PKCS#7/CMS or OpenPGP depending on whether you prefer to deal with X.509 certificates (they can be self-signed) or PGP keys. Both technologies provide comparable level of security and the differences (in case of your task) are mainly in the key format.

BouncyCastle or our SecureBlackbox are the widely used libraries suitable for both variants.